# List index out of range using sys.argv in python

Tags: python, module

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXQGI.png)I am a beginner programmer, I've written a guess random number game as per tutor of udemy on pycharm community version which has only python not python3. As my tutor's program is going fine but my program is giving error "list index out of range". My program as below:

```
from random import randint
import sys
#generate a number
answer = randint(int(sys.argv[1]),int(sys.argv[2]))

#input from user
#check that input is a number 1~10
while True:
    try:
        guess = int(input('guess a number 1~10:  '))
        if 0<guess<10:
            if guess == answer:
                print('you are genius')
                break
        else:
            print('hey boy, I said 1~10')
    except ValueError:
        print('please enter a number')
        continue
```

Comment: Are you passing atleast 2 arguments to the program when you're running it

Comment: No my program is giving error at the first of run. But in my program I have given two arguments just to create a list between 1~10 integer numbers

Comment: How are you running the program What's the command? `python ...`?

Comment: @rdas Thanks for your reply. Actually I was not passing two arguments from terminal thats why it was giving error of "list index out of range". I got point from your comment and solved my issue.